# SSIS: t-sql command getdate() loads current date but not time portion

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, ssis, getdate

I have a t-sql command set up in an ole db source object:

ex:

```
select getdate() as LoadDate, customerid from dbo.customer
```

in the preview window of SSIS it shows the current date and time as I want it.

However, after I run the task and look at the destination table, the table shows the current date but the time portion is 00:00:00:000. I am wanting to see the time portion in addition to the date.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: when you insert that row, you must check if the destination field is date instead of datetime

Comment: I double checked and the destination field is in fact datetime.

Comment: Do you have any other transformations going on in the task? Or is it just Source to Destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation once where the problem was on my source, not on the destination.

I suggest you to check the field on the SourceComponent by right clicking it, selecting Show Advanced editor -> input and Output properties -> Expand "Output columns" -> Select your column and change to the proper data type (usually [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] works fine for me). Also for the sake of testing, do the same on "Output columns"

Comment: Thanks! The output data type was set to [DT_DBTIMESTAMP], I changed it to [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2] and that did the trick. In searching for this resolution, I read using getdate() with seconds would increment the value since it was being called each row but not here. The value is constant throughout each row (1000 records).